# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null with custom element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I created a web component and i gave it a method.. When the button is pressed I want the method to show "Hello" but its not working at all, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

I would like to know why is this happening and how I can fix this?

My JS code:

```
var WC = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

WC.hi= function() {
    document.getElementById("w-c").value = "Hello!";
};

var WCR = document.registerElement("w-c", {
    prototype: WC, 
    extends:'input'
});

var wc = new WCR();

var division = document.getElementById('sh');
var root = division.createShadowRoot();
root.appendChild(wc);

WC.setDimensions = function() {
    Object.defineProperty(WC, 'height', {value: 1000});
};
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h2>WEB COMPONENT</h2>
                <div id="sh"> </div>
        <script src="webcomponent.js"> </script>
            <button onclick="wc.hi()">
                    Say hi</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no element with the id `w-c`.

Comment: Add the id of the button

Comment: @the4kman and how can i access to the custom input element? i thought it has the id w-c since i registered like that

Comment: @RajendranNadar i want to change the value of the custom input element not the button

Comment: make sure the registerElement is called before you call the function

Comment: Whers is the input element?

Comment: in the script webcomponent.js @RajendranNadar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with id "w-c" does not exist. Either create it, or use `document.createElement`

EDIT:

```
var newEl = document.createElement("div");
/*apply styles here*/
newEl.id = "w-c";
document.appendChild(newEl);
```

Comment: when i use document.createElement the custom element doesnt show, how can i fix this?

Comment: var newEl = document.createElement("div");/*apply styles here*/newEl.id="w-c";document.appendChild(newEl);